# Understanding wait and interrupt from Java Language Specification

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to understand threads and locks from Java Language Specifications [chapter 17](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html). It says:

(Quote 1)

> Let `t` be the thread invoking `u.interrupt`, for some thread `u`, where `t` and `u` may be the same. This action causes `u`'s interruption status to be set to `true`.

I believe this corresponds to sentence "If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be set." from the `Thread.interrupt()` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

**Q1.** Am I right?

It further says:

(Quote 2)

> Additionally, if there exists some object `m` whose wait set contains `u`, then `u` is removed from `m`'s wait set. This enables `u` to resume in a wait action, in which case this wait will, after re-locking `m`'s monitor, throw `InterruptedException`.

I believe this correspond to the sentence "If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait()`, `wait(long)`, or `wait(long, int)` methods of the `Object` class, or of the `join()`, `join(long)`, `join(long, int)`, `sleep(long)`, or `sleep(long, int)`, methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`." from `Thread.interrupt()` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()).

**Q2.** Am I right?
**Q3.** What does it mean by "enables u to resume in a wait action, in which case this wait will, after re-locking `m`'s monitor, throw `InterruptedException`"

It further says:

(Quote 3)

> If a thread is both notified and interrupted while waiting, it may either:
>
> - return normally from `wait`, while still having a pending interrupt (in other words, a call to `Thread.interrupted` would return true)
> - return from wait by throwing an `InterruptedException`
>     The thread may not reset its interrupt status and return normally from the call to wait

**Q4.** Does the last statement correspond to the first bullet point?

(Quote 4)

> Similarly, notifications cannot be lost due to interrupts. Assume that a set s`` of threads is in the wait set of an object `m`, and another thread performs a notify on `m`. Then either:
>
> - at least one thread in `s` must return normally from wait, or
> - all of the threads in `s` must exit wait by throwing `InterruptedException`
>
> Note that if a thread is both interrupted and woken via notify, and that thread returns from wait by throwing an `InterruptedException`, then some other thread in the wait set must be notified.

**Q5.** Does above last sentence correspond to 2nd bullet points from 3rd quote?

**Q6.** How / why 2nd bullet point holds, specifically "all"?

I don't get logic behind following sentence from the `Thread.interrupt()` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()):

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the `wait()`, `wait(long)`, or `wait(long, int)` methods of the `Object` class, or of the `join()`, `join(long)`, `join(long, int)`, `sleep(long)`, or `sleep(long, int)`, methods of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an `InterruptedException`.

**Q7.** Does it mean, by getting out of wait / sleep / join, the reaction or response to `interrupt()` is complete and hence clear the interrupt and indicate that the interrupt and its response happened by raising `InterruptedException`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only going to attempt to answer one of your several questions:

> Q3. What does it mean by "enables u to resume in a wait action, in which case this wait will, after re-locking m's monitor, throw InterruptedException"

Piece by piece:

> enables u to resume

Just what it says on the tin: Thread u, which was blocked in a call to `m.wait()`, will stop waiting for some other thread to call `m.notify()`.

> ...after re-locking m's monitor...

Because `m.wait()` must *never* return without first re-locking the monitor. It doesn't matter whether `m.wait()` returns normally or abnormally*. The reason is, the handler for the exception could be inside the `synchronized (m)` block, and a thread must never execute inside a `synchronized` block without holding the monitor.

> ...throw InterruptedException

Again, just what it says on the tin: The `m.wait()` call will throw an exception instead of returning normally.

---

* When a function throws an exception, that event is called an "abnormal return"  in some documentation contexts.

Comment: I guess I understood "enables u to resume in a wait action". **Qx.** Does it simply mean allows `u` to stop waiting for `m`? Now, I am only struggling for "after re-locking m's monitor". I also didn't get "must never return without first re-locking the monitor..." in your answer. I understand that if we lock object, we lock monitor associated with it. **Qy.** How waiting for a thread deals (un/re/locking) with monitor associated with thread object?

Comment: @anir, Re, "**Qx**..." Yes. That's pretty much what I said. To put it a different way; If some thread `t` is waiting in an `m.wait()` call, and some other thread calls `t.interrupt()`, then thread `t` will stop waiting for a notification, it will start trying to re-acquire the monitor of object `m`, and after it acquires the monitor, it will throw an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Re, "**Qy**..." I don't understand what you are asking. I don't know what it would mean for a thread to _deal with_ releasing and re-acquiring the monitor. It just _does_ those things.

Comment: It says "..after re-locking m's monitor..". I was not aware why `wait()` relocks monitor. I never found any text describing how `wait()`, locks, unlocks and relocks monitor. Just found in [`Object.wait()`](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)). Interpreting doc, is it like: (1) Current thread is put in wait set of this object (2) Current thread relinquich all sync claims on this object (3) After notify or interrupt, current thread is removed from wait set for this object. (4) It competes with other threads to get back sync claims.

Comment: [..continued from above comment] **Qu.** So is (4) like, current thread "automatically" starts competing for getting back sync claims of this object as soon as it is removed from wait set, without any explicit API (`lock()`) call? We were talking about `wait()`, which involves current thread getting into wait set of `this` object. **Qv.** Is it same for `lock(m1)` call (which involves current thread getting into wait set of `m1`'s wait set)?

Comment: Re, "I never found any text describing how `wait()`..., unlocks and relocks monitor." Do you mean, you never found any text declaring _that_ it does those things?  It's all there in the [Javadoc for the `java.lang.Object` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long,int)). OTOH, if you really meant you don't understand _how_ it does those things, then you could read the [OpenJDK source code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk13/file/) (NOTE: Object.wait(...) calls a `native` method,) but you don't actually need to know _how_ in order to use it.

Comment: I meant "earlier" I never found. But then I wrote "Just found in `Object.wait()`...". (Sorry to not including "earlier") The remaining part of comment after  "Just found in `Object.wait()`..." is what I understood and in comment after that (my last comment), I have stated doubts about my understanding.